# ScrollView not wrapping children layout changes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a content page with a stack layout as parent and a 'scrollview' as a single child. The 'scrollview' also contains a single child as follows:

```
<StackLayout
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Orientation = "Vertical"
    BackgroundColor = "Green">

    <ScrollView
        x:Name = "scrMain"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Orientation = "Vertical">

        <StackLayout
                x:Name = "slMain"
                VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                Orientation = "Vertical"
                Padding = "10,0,10,0"
                >
```

...

Now I have a code that changes the height of one of 'slMain' children and that the its height is expanded. My problem is, scrollview is not following this changes and only keeps its content size clipping the expanded layout short. I'm new to this platform so please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Note: Im using Xamarin.Forms V2.3.3.175

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Can you add screenshots of what happens?

Comment: Also, this might help: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/66248/#Comment_66248

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code for C#:

```
scrollView.IsClippedToBounds = true;
```

or to your code for xaml:

```
    <ScrollView
        x:Name = "scrMain"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        IsClippedToBounds = "true"
        Orientation = "Vertical">
```